# Solr Spatial search with self-intersecting polygons

Tags: search, solr, polygon, spatial, intersection

I’m using Solr 4.3.0 with an up to date version of JTS and spatial4j. As field type in my `schema.xml`  i’m using “location_rpt” like the description in the documentation.
[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#How_to_Use)

```
<field name="standort" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Now when my Application create a FilterQuery like this

```
standort:"IsWithin (POLYGON((16.243972778320312 48.27016879304729, 16.411170959472656 48.268340583150504, 16.44275665283203 48.19058119922813, 16.32396697998047 48.15921534239267,16.243972778320312 48.27016879304729)))
```

everything works fine. My problem is when im trying to use a more complex polygon (self-intersecting) Solr only shows an Error like this:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: Self-intersection at or near point (16.315572194579204, 48.26688289499306, NaN)
```

the corresponding query looks like this:

```
standort:"IsWithin (POLYGON((16.253585815429688 48.27748097861045, 16.506271362304688 48.23427822033628, 16.418380737304688 48.18646123261718, 16.286544799804688 48.28958948415696,16.253585815429688 48.27748097861045)))"
```

[Screen of the Polygon](https://www.dropbox.com/s/suzeu61wjouhea2/spatial_search.png)

Are there any workarounds to get self-intersecting polgyon querys to work?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use "IsWithin" *if* all your indexed data is points -- use "Intersects".  IsWithin will work but it's much slower because it handles indexed non-point shapes.  In the future, you'll be expected to declare in the field type wether your indexed data is strictly points or more than that so that Solr can internally do the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really.  You can use JTS on the client to clean up your polygon so that when Solr gets it, it's valid.  See http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/jts-faq/jts-faq.html#G

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using PHP as client side programming language. Do you know any php library which is capable of solving my problem like JTS would do?

Comment: I don't know if the PHP world has something (try googling it?).  However perhaps you can use a JavaScript solution?: https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts  (a JavaScript port of JTS)