# Solr spatial search , polygon intersect error

Tags: search, solr, lucene, spatial, jts

I am trying spatial search in SOLR 5.0 , My system are up and running, but sometimes I am coming across this error, I have google it around but found no explanation as such, anyone please help me with this.

**My Error**

```
because: com.spatial4j.core.exception.InvalidShapeException: Self-intersection at or near point 
(13.143009111281323, 80.07316589355469, NaN)","code":400}})
```

**My Query :**

```
Intersects(POLYGON((13.142340452070176 80.07522583007812,13.141003126359843 80.079345703125
,13.141003126359843 80.08621215820312,13.1383284530778 80.09445190429688,13.1383284530778 80.101318359375
,13.136991105507466 80.11367797851562,13.131641642380112 80.14114379882812,13.128966867118496 80.15350341796875
,13.126292062732247 80.16311645507812,13.124954649619115 80.17135620117188,13.111580118251648 80.17135620117188
,13.099542418228534 80.15899658203125,13.095529720741494 80.10543823242188,13.09820485966459 80.10543823242188
,13.099542418228534 80.10406494140625,13.102217513557752 80.10406494140625,13.103555050321653 80.10269165039062
,13.106230102044576 80.101318359375,13.114255082724767 80.101318359375,13.1155925540513 80.09994506835938
,13.118267474880913 80.09857177734375,13.119604924382593 80.09857177734375,13.124954649619115 80.0958251953125
,13.127629468565612 80.0958251953125,13.130304258390225 80.09445190429688,13.131641642380112 80.09445190429688
,13.134316388511614 80.09307861328125,13.136991105507466 80.09033203125,13.139665793362148 80.0848388671875
,13.141003126359843 80.08346557617188,13.141003126359843 80.08209228515625,13.142340452070176 80.08071899414062
,13.142340452070176 80.0738525390625,13.14367777049247 80.07247924804688,13.14367777049247 80.07110595703125
,13.142340452070176 80.07522583007812)))distErrPct=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's take a look at the polygon:

[image: full plot]

Looks reasonable, but pretty busy in the lower right:

[image: Zoom in on lower right]

There you can see the self-intersection, and self-intersecting polygons aren't acceptable (see [Solr Spatial search with self-intersecting polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613561/solr-spatial-search-with-self-intersecting-polygons) for some more information on that).

It looks to me like you're trying to be more precise than your application is capable of.

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon, actualy m trying to draw free hand polygon on google map.. anyways I seen that many people were telling to make jts buffer (0) ..how ii need to done ?? Any idea ?